# React native ios "Native Module cannot be null"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

i try to run my react native code in ios simulator, but i keep get this error on my simulator,
I already did *npx pod-install* but this error keep coming

this problem only appear on ios, in android it work fine

error detail:

---

[image]

---

react native info:

---

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.3
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 438.08 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.12.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 5.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
    Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
    react-native: 0.60.6 => 0.60.6 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
    react-native-rename: 2.4.1
```

---

my package.js:

---

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.4.0",
    "geolib": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.6",
    "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.3",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-options-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.12",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0"
  },
```

---

podfile:

---

[image]

---

any solution for my issue?

Comment: what library  have you downloaded the latest

Comment: @GauravRoy, react-native-image-crop-picker, i updating that library last time, but i don't know that couse the issue because i never run on ios before update that library